# Specflow configure stopAfterFailures and retryFor by code

Tags: c#, specflow, specrun

I am using Specflow with MsTest and C#.

I can configure stopAfterFailures and retryFor using Default.srprofile which applied to all scenario, but i want to configure it by code may be in Hooks. So i can configure it feature wise.

How can I configure Specrun stopAfterFailures and retryFor programatically during the test run?

Comment: There is no question in your post. What do you want to achieve and what have you already tried?

Comment: When you have a Default.srprofile you are using SpecRun as TestRunner and not MsTest.
Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, using SpecRun as TestRunner. I configured stopAfterFailures and retryFor using Default.srprofile and it's working, i'm trying to configure it by code means feature specific configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it is not possible to change this values during test run.

What we added in SpecRun 1.3 (not yet released) is, that there will be an API to cancel the whole test run.